# Renting a private room monthly in NYC at an affordable price without getting Scam or Spam

Tags: accommodation, rental

## Original question

I am planning to flight from Italy to NYC for three months with a Visa category B-2 that I already own.

I do not have an exact budget to spend but it’s not going to be high. And so the affordable way to sleep in a reserved context, seems to be renting a private room (there are plenty for a max 700$ per month not too far the public transportations) but I found out that it’s full of scammers that asking for the money in advance and then disappearing see [Cirtru.com](https://www.cirtru.com/) scam chat [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUTUf.jpg), or spammers that get data and reuse for other advertisements see this spam email [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Qec.jpg)

I read about Rent Escrow [Gov here](https://ag.ny.gov/sites/default/files/tenants_rights.pdf) and [here](https://www.thebalance.com/what-is-rent-escrow-5190759) but it’s unclear how and who could handle it.

The cheapest and the only way to do not get scammed or spammed, seems to be renting a bed in a hostel dorm for a few days on the arrival, then filter a search in [newyork.craigslist](https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/hhh?availabilityMode=0&max_price=700&private_room=1&rent_period=3) and contact all the interesting list so to ask for a visit in person. But I am trying to contact them and nobody is picking up the phone, I also left pretty text messages but no reply yet since two days, so I would avoid the risk to stay too long at the hostel because no one will be available to offer a private room for renting.

If I could express a desire I would avoid the hostel stay, and rent the private room beside the flight tickets, with a guarantee of a trust. I know that Airbnb is indeed a trust, but seems that all the well known platforms like that, are pushing too high the prices, maybe because the marketing costs, the fees that landlords has to pay and the popularity that such platforms acquired are pushing too much high the prices on the market for tourists.

Am I missing any detail? Do you have any related advise?

Ciao, ciao.

Comment: Maybe the 'too high prices' are the new normal? At least, AirBnB gives you the security that it is no scam. How much is that worth to you?

Comment: I have used AirBnB for three-month stays successfully, and you often get a 20% or higher discount for booking more than 30 days. But it seems your mind is made up, so sure, find another solution.

Comment: You probably won’t get a 3-month stay at the rate if a tenancy for a year or longer (because handling tenant changes is a hassle and often costly). Airbnb has specific offers for stays of a few months, prices (and availabilities) may be quite different from those for stays of a few days.

Comment: I know you don't see yourself as a tourist, but a B-2 is a tourist visa, and under 6-12 months is a tourist length of stay. You don't have the options students or residents have by being able to sign annual contracts, and even for them, NYC is **expensive**.

Comment: @Ax_ I would, uh, not mention those work plans to immigration; you don't have authorization to work in the US under a B-2 visa. The point, again, is that your options for accommodation are going to be the ones available to other tourists; hotels, AirBnB, etc.

Comment: I do not think your question really fits expatriates, our sister site, as it is, as you are looking for a shorter term visitors visit to NYC, but as you are looking for a longer period of renting than most people traveling as visitors will do, you might ask a question there, with information which is to the point for a 3 month visit. The people on that site do look at mid and long stays rather than the short stays on this site. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @Ax_, it might be better to just react on specific comments in comments and keep the edits to the question more general, that is the way that is the norm on Travel Stack Exchange.

Comment: Rolled back because you changed the details of the question in such a way that the answers did not fit, while they did fit your original question.

Answer (score 12):

If the only prices that you find acceptable are scams then you're not going to have much luck at your current price range. NYC is one of the most expensive places to live on earth, you can't magically expect to be able to stay there cheaply just because you set your budget low. This is especially true for short-term lets.

A reputable company like Airbnb is realistically going to be the best and safest way to find accommodation. You can always book to stay at one for a couple of weeks and then see if the owner is receptive to doing a deal with you directly for the rest of your stay.

Comment: yes, $700/month sounds *way* too cheap for apartments in NYC, even tiny 1-bed studios.

Comment: `there are hundreds between $500 and $700 downtown’s the city centres of NYC main neighbourhoods` there are hundreds that are scams and probably zero that are real.

Comment: Whenever I onsite in NYC, I stay somewhere far out. Unlike most of North America, New York City has a vast, dense (again, for North America) commuter rail system https://nycmap360.com/carte/pdf/en/nyc-rail-map.pdf but sometimes just staying in a sufficiently rundown part of Queens will bring the price down significantly and the F or the 7 takes you to Manhattan in a snap.